# Setting Class path in Tomcat7 to solve NoClassDefNotFound error

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, classpath

I recently deployed a web app that I built in eclipse to an AWS ec2 instance. Worked fine in eclipse but got a NoClassDefNotFound error on my server. I wrote a test main method in my servlet and was able to get rid of the error by running

```
java -cp .:(class paths to all imported classes). packageName.myservlet
```

So my question is how do I configure tomcat7 to include the class paths I did to get my servlet running properly, thanks.

```
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/ArtGallery]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/java/tomcat7/log4j.jar], exists: [false] canRead:[false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/java/tomcat7/log4j.jar], exists: [false] canRead:[false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/tomcat7/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/j2ee.jar]exists:[false],canRead:[false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory[/usr/share/tomcat7/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ArtGallery/WEB-INF/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/tomcat7/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/j2ee.jar], exists: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory[/usr/share/tomcat7/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ArtGallery/WEB-INF/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2014 10:53:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Here some suspicious warning I found in catalina.out, and below is what I can use to get the servlet to run my test main method.

```
java -classpath .:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/j2ee.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ArtGallery/WEB-INF/lib/* ArtworkServlet/ArtworkDB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log file it seems there is an issue with Your tomcat installation. 
see the commenta For more info.

as brute Force Solution I suggest to reinstall tomcat.

working with the classpath is not the right way to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot to specify that the .jar files I had to include when I used java -cp are included in WEB-INF/lib so it seems like tomcat isn't even looking there.

Comment: It seems a deployment issue, can you describe Your deployment process? (eg export a war from eclipse,...)

Comment: This is my first time doing this so that could very well be the case. I made the project in Eclipse and tested locally, I then exported the project as a .war file and sent that to my ec2 instance through sftp, and put it in the tomcat/webapps directory.

Comment: The deployment is good. Can you post the stacktrace? What happens if you try to deploy the war in a tomcat local installation without using eclipse? On ec2 in the Catalina.out have you seen some deployment logs?

Comment: Added what I found in the catalina.out, the stack trace just shows the NoClassDefFoundError and a ClassNotFoundException because of the NoClassDef. It works like a dream if I deploy it locally. This is a problem I have seen asked about without any solution several times so if we could figure this out you'd be a hero.

Comment: usr/share/tomcat7/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ArtGallery/WEB-INF/lib not found... Your jar is in this folder, so this is the reason why classnotfound is throw. You need to fix tomcat installation. Look at the path in the log, the sub path usr/share/tomcat7 appear twice, this is strange, so on, why there is a jvm installation inside usr/share/tomcat7? It seems wrong. These folders really exists? If you will fix the warnings your app will work. As brute Force solution uninstall and install tomcat,

Comment: That was it, if you want, edit the answer with this and I'll mark it as answered. I want to make sure you get the credit. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. the more important thing is that you have solved Your problem.